# Tkinter canvas image transition

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I want to have some transition to show the images in the canvas, I'm using Tkinter and I'm looping through the images to show them on the canvas but I need to have some transition while switching among the images.
I'm using `canvasName.create_image` method for showing the images. Need a way to show them smoothly.

Here is my code:

```
def Multi_view_rotate():
    window.geometry(str(scr_w)+"x"+str(scr_h)+"+0+0")
    z_out = 20
    
    global timeSleep
    timeSleepVal = int(timeSleep.get())
    global footerPath
    footerPath = footerPath.get()
    #geting director from entry boxes
    global portDirEntry
    portDirEntry = portDirEntry.get()
    
    global colorEntry
    bgcolor = colorEntry.get()
    
    allPaths = getPaths(portDirEntry)
    
    #directory = r"C:\Users\DotNet\Desktop\Ragazinana Data reduced\diashow\4 Random\Landschaft"
    #Get paths
    pathsPrt = allPaths[0]
    pathsLand = allPaths[1]
    #read the image 
    #call the function to get the picture object with new size
    global numOfImagesPort
    global numOfImagesLand
    #footer path
    #footerPath = "C:/Users/DotNet/Desktop/Ragazinana Data reduced/diashow/ragaziana_s.jpg"
    
    #Footer will take 8% of the screen width   
    per_w_footer = cal_per_num(8, scr_w)
    # Footer Image operations
    canvasFoot = Canvas(window,width=per_w_footer, height=scr_h, bg=bgcolor, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground=bgcolor)
    canvasFoot.grid(row=0, column=0)
    #footerImg = get_img_fit_size(footerPath, scr_h, per_w_footer, True)
    footerImg1 = Image.open(footerPath)
    footerImg2 = footerImg1.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270)
    footerImg3 = footerImg2.resize((int(per_w_footer),int(scr_h)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    footerImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(footerImg3)
    footer = canvasFoot.create_image(per_w_footer/2,scr_h/2,anchor=CENTER, image=footerImg)
    
    
    while(numOfImagesPort<=len(pathsPrt)-1 or numOfImagesLand<=len(pathsLand)-1 ):
        
        pathPort = pathsPrt[numOfImagesPort]
        #increase the index to get the next file in the next loop
        numOfImagesPort=numOfImagesPort+1
        #if the next photo is out of bound then assign it to the first index
        if(numOfImagesPort >= len(pathsPrt)):# if total is 5 pic, 1st loop 0 > 6 /reset the loop   
            numOfImagesPort=0
            
        # each image will take as following in percentage
        per_w_imgs_portriate = cal_per_num(42, scr_w)
        per_w_imgs_landscape= cal_per_num(50, scr_w)

        #Create the canvases
        canvasPort = Canvas(window,width=per_w_imgs_portriate, height=scr_h, bg=bgcolor, highlightthickness=10, highlightbackground=bgcolor)
        
        #gird plays the canvas without it the canvas will not work
        canvasPort.grid(row=0, column=1)

        #in order to make the picture fit in the rotated state in the half of the screen
        # we make the get_img_fit_size adjust it to us to that size by providing 
        # screen hight  as a width and half of the screen with as a height
        imgPort = get_img_fit_size(pathPort, scr_h, per_w_imgs_landscape, True)
        
        portImgCanvas = canvasPort.create_image(int(scr_w/4.3),int(scr_h/2),anchor=CENTER, image=imgPort)**
        window.update()
    
        time.sleep(timeSleepVal/2)
        
        # Landscape image 
        pathLand = pathsLand[numOfImagesLand]
        numOfImagesLand = numOfImagesLand+1
        
        if(numOfImagesLand >= len(pathsLand)):
            numOfImagesLand=0
            
        
        canvasLand = Canvas(window,width=per_w_imgs_landscape, height=scr_h, bg=bgcolor, highlightthickness=10, highlightbackground=bgcolor)
        canvasLand.grid(row=0, column=2)
        imgLand = get_img_fit_size(pathLand, scr_h, per_w_imgs_portriate, True)
        landImgCanvas = canvasLand.create_image(int(scr_w/4.5),int(scr_h/2),anchor=CENTER, image=imgLand)
        
                
        window.update()
        time.sleep(timeSleepVal/2)
        
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you mean "transition", like gradually fading from one image to the other?

Comment: Also, please try to reduce your code to the minimum that is needed to illustrate and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant transition!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something like this built into `Tkinter.PhotoImage`, but you could manually create a "fade" transition by randomly selecting pixels and setting them to the color values of the next image:

```
import tkinter, random

root = tkinter.Tk()
c = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=400)
c.pack()

img_a = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="a.gif")
img_b = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="b.gif")

i = c.create_image(0, 0, image=img_a, anchor="nw")

pixels = [(x, y) for x in range(img_a.width()) for y in range(img_a.height())]
random.shuffle(pixels)

def fade(n=1000):
    global pixels, i
    for _ in range(min(n, len(pixels))):
        x, y = pixels.pop()
        col = "#%02x%02x%02x" % img_b.get(x,y)
        img_a.put(col, (x, y))
    
    c.delete(i)
    i = c.create_image(0, 0, image=img_a, anchor="nw")
    if pixels:
        c.after(1, fade)

fade()
root.mainloop()
```

This is *slow*, though. The `after` with 1 ms is only to keep the UI from freezing (don't use `while` with `time.sleep` in `Tkinter`!). For a smoother transition, instead of replacing pixel values you might gradually shift all pixels towards the values in the next image, but that will be even slower since you'd change all pixels in each step.

Instead of pure `tkinter`, we can try it wit `PIL` and `numpy`, but it is not noticeably faster, and least not the way I did it:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import islice

...    

arr_a = np.array(Image.open("a.gif").convert("RGB"))
arr_b = np.array(Image.open("b.gif").convert("RGB"))

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(arr_a, mode="RGB"))
i = c.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")

h, w, _ = arr_a.shape
pixels = [(x, y) for x in range(w) for y in range(h)]
random.shuffle(pixels)

def fade(k=0, n=1000):
    global i, img
    X, Y = zip(*islice(pixels, k, k+n))
    arr_a[Y,X] = arr_b[Y,X]
    
    c.delete(i)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(arr_a, mode="RGB"))
    i = c.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")
    if k + n < w * h:
        c.after(1, fade, k+n, n)

fade()
root.mainloop()
```

However, this also allows us to replace entire lines at once. The effect is not quite as nice, but it is *much* faster (also note changed `n` and `if` condition).

```
...

h, w, _ = arr_a.shape
lines = list(range(h))
random.shuffle(lines)

def fade(k=0, n=10):
    global i, img
    Y = lines[k:k+n]
    arr_a[Y] = arr_b[Y]
    
    ...
    if k + n < h:
        c.after(1, fade, k+n, n)

...
```

This can also easily be transformed to a vertical or horizontal slide transition by simply not shuffling the lines (for columns, use `arr_a[:,X] = arr_b[:,X]`).